# CakePHP Form Action Button

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to place a non form related button into the view for a registration button to direct people to a controller action but i continue to get error500 internal error. Any ideas what i am doing wrong here?

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Session->flash();
echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label' => false, 'div' => false, 'class' => 'w-icon validate[required]'));
echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => false, 'div' => false, 'class' => 'w-icon validate[required]'));
echo $form->button('Register', array('type' => 'button', 'class' => 'button red tiny'));
echo $this->Form->submit('Login', array('class' => 'button blue tiny'));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$form->button` is CakePHP 1.2 syntax, `$this->Form` is 1.3 onwards.

Comment: thank you for this! how would i make the button point to a controller/action instead of being a submit button?

Comment: Buttons do not point to anything, they submit forms. That is how HTML works. You can use a link to go to something else. $this->Html->link(...)

Comment: final solution was echo $this->Form->button('Register', array('onclick' => "location.href='/register'", 'class' => 'button red tiny'));